# Crofton's Fixed Point Formula and Jensen's Inequality

Tags: differential-geometry

I am currently working on a paper that investigates the communication between UAVs modelled in 3D geometry. I came across a work that combined Crofton's Fixed Point Formula and Jensen's Inequality. My specialty is not in Mathematics but Engineering and I will love to ask how the two concepts they correlate and are useful in 3D Geometry.

Thanks

Comment: Please make your post more self-contained. I know plenty about Crofton's formula in integral geometry, but have no idea what the Fixed Point Formula is to which you refer.  And which Jensen's inequality are you referring to that is being tied in?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @TedShifrin I truly appreciate your prompt assistance. However, being new to the platform, I am concerned that I may not have effectively communicated the mathematical formulations with the accuracy and clarity they deserve.

Therefore, I would like to kindly request your permission to provide further elaboration on my submission via email. This would allow me to present the mathematical concepts in a more comprehensive and self-contained manner.